# Has Facebook started blocking posting on Friend's wall?

Tags: facebook

Anyone Kindly suggest, has Facebook started blocking posting on friend's wall?
Since in my previous application I tried posting images, links, text etc in my friends facebook wall it was working fine and better, but suddenly after February I am not able to post information to my friends wall.

Comment: What is a response you get from FB when you try to do it?

Comment: this is the error im getting while trying to post it on the wall. `
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/doodlecl/public_html/front_apps/controllers/src/base_facebook.php on line 1039`

Comment: Did you get correct permission to do it? You have to first authorize the user, and then ask for permission to write to the wall.

Comment: can you share your email ID so that I can send the code to you, of how I am using the authorization and wall post etc.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have removed this ability from the api. You can only post to your own wall. There is a blog post about it somewhere on their developer blog and you can see it is on the completed roadmap https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/  (search for "Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API " )

If you want to post to another users wall Facebook advise you to invoke the Feed dialog

Comment: is it possible to use Feed dialog in PHP, Since for my application i am not allowed to use Javascript.

Comment: see the "Direct URL" section at the bottom here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/