# PHP-SDK publish_stream?

Tags: facebook

When I try to publish on the walls of friends, it does not work. I don't know where the problem is. Can somebody help me?

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.your-website.com',
                                  'message' => 'Hello World!'
                             ));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>'publish_stream','redirect_uri'=>'http://your-website/index.html'));
  die('<script> top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>');
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you can't post to a friends wall via the api? Or that when a friend uses your app they can't post to their own wall?

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are calling an end point for "me" for the publish action. Which means you are publishing to the wall of the current user, not a friend. Further to this, facebook has removed the ability to post on Friend's walls via the graph api refer to my previous answer here [Has Facebook started blocking posting on Friend's wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121328/has-facebook-started-blocking-posting-on-friends-wall/16123088#16123088)

If it's not working for a friend using your app to post to their own wall, make sure they have the appropriate permissions set (you can always use the me/permissions) endpoint to check this

Comment: What can i do now can i publish using  javascript can you help me?

Comment: Can you answer my comment above and clarify your problem?

Comment: yes really i want to publish to the wall of the current user! who use my app i want to publish in his wall?